# What code i need to input, and where, to switch to a different fragment once item is clicked?

Tags: java, android, fragment, drawer

on my activity_main_drawer i got many items but i don't know what code and where it goes to add for switching fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contests"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rules"
            android:icon="@drawable/irules"
            android:title="@string/box_contest_rules" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_face_24"
            android:title="@string/profile_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
            android:icon="@drawable/icalendar"
            android:title="@string/calendar_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/igallery"
            android:title="@string/gallery_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stats"
            android:icon="@drawable/istats"
            android:title="@string/stats_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rank"
            android:icon="@drawable/irank"
            android:title="@string/rank_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_shop"
            android:icon="@drawable/ishop"
            android:title="@string/shop_page" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
            android:title="@string/setting_page" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

this is the java HomePage where i am struggling to understand where and what code to add

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

and this is one of the fragment java as example.

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

it would be great as example to switch from HomePage to GalleryFragment and back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try-->

put this in your mainactivity:-

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.nav_contests) {
//intent to next activity


} else if (id == R.id.nav_rules) {
 //just an example
 String message = "Text I want to share.";
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));


} else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

 ///your actions
}
} else if (id == R.id.nav_calendar) {

}
 } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

}
} else if (id == R.id.nav_stats) {

}




DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```

****Demo****

**main_activity:**

```
package ijsolutions.appnav;

import android.os.Bundle;
 import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_home);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Menu1();
            //ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            fragment = new Menu2();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            fragment = new Menu3();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            break;

    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    //make this method blank
    return true;
}}
```

**Menu1**

```
public class Menu1 extends Fragment {


public Menu1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu1, container, false);
}
```

}

**xml of menu1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Menu1"
android:background="#68a">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/Home"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
  />
```

***so am not puting the rest menus as it is same***

**activitymain xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_drawer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/menu_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="@string/menu_send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
 </menu>
```

**content_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**app_bar_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: on R.id.yourid1 i put nav_gallery but not sure on R.id.yourid2 and R.id.anything what to put?

Comment: put your menu item ids....nav_rules,nav_profile,nav_calendar ...so on

Comment: Wini, sorry I am very new at this and I really want to understand. But on the code you gave me i see R.id.yourid1, R.id.yourid2 and R.id.yourid.anything in red. I assume the R.id.yourid1 is where I want to go after I click the button, what about the other 2?

Comment: ok, and on // on your action, i assume i need to put what i want to do once the id is clicked? for example i want to move to fragment_gallery?

Comment: yes do actions like if you want to go to next activity like fragmentgallery then :--- `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  
startActivity(i);`

Comment: @mz4466  did solution worked for you?let me know if it doesnt

Comment: is doing anything. I put if (id == R.id.nav_contests) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);   startActivity(i);
            
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryFragment.class);   startActivity(i);

Comment: so you got what you wanted..?@mz4466

Comment: what I meant is that is not working. nothing happens

Comment: didnt it take you to GalleryFragment class?

Comment: it all make sense but did not take anywhere.

Comment: i will put a whole demo based on navigation drawer...in few minutes...so that you could understand

Comment: NOTE:---dont add this whole code demo in your current project....just make a new one project..then add and run ....lastly understand the flow like how it works..then add in your current project....in demo if you still find any error let me know

Answer (score 0):

Add in you activity. It works

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            logOut(HomePage.this, "Logout due to nav. logout");
        }
        
        
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
  }
```

Comment: nav_logout and logout are in red

Comment: You need to use your menu item id's.

Comment: i this this is the problem. i got only this on ids <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="text_home" type="id"/>
</resources>